# Why does a chromebook call out to these non existent domains?

Tags: dns, wireshark, sniffing, chromebook

Is this one of their forms of checking for a captive portal or what?

[image: Chromebook pcap]

Comment: Could you please add the data as text instead of a screenshot?

Comment: You have malware....

Comment: @Tyson Uh, it's a Chromeboook... Google made them for general ease of use and since it's heavily locked down it virtually *can't* get malware

Comment: @JoshM if the browser supports extensions the it can get infected. Just because the operating system might be hardened doesn't mean that malware can't burrow into the browser itself and do a lot of mischief.

Comment: Its not Malware its a brand new chromebook.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior for Chrome, and is used to detect DNS redirection by ISPs.

Someone has already answered in detail here:

https://serverfault.com/a/235328/372528